# How to stop Eclipse formatter from placing all enums on one line

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I have enums like:

```
public static enum Command
{
login,
register,
logout,
newMessage
}
```

When formatting the file, the output becomes:

```
public static enum Command 
{
login, register, logout, newMessage
}
```

Comment: Is there any variable in external formatter (org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter......) to enforce each enum variable in a separate line?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The answer by @wjans worked fine for normal enums, but not for enums with arguments. To expand on his answer a bit, here's the settings that provided the most sensible formatting for me in Eclipse Juno:

1. `Window` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Code Style` > `Formatter`
2. Click `Edit`
3. Select the `Line Wrapping` tab
4. Select the `enum` declaration treenode
5. Set `Line wrapping policy` to `Wrap all elements, every element on a new line (...)` so it now says 3 of 3 in the parenthesis.
6. Uncheck `Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width (...)` so it now says 3 of 3 in the parenthesis.
7. Select the `Constants` treenode
8. Check `Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width`

This sets the 3 subnodes for the enum treenode to the same wrapping policy, and the same force split policy except for the `Constants` treenode, so your enums with arguments will be formatted each on their own line. The arguments will only wrap if they exceed maximum line width.

**Examples:**

**@wjans**

```
enum Example {
    CANCELLED,
    RUNNING,
    WAITING,
    FINISHED
}

enum Example {
    GREEN(
        0,
        255,
        0),
    RED(
        255,
        0,
        0)
}
```

**Solution described above:**

```
enum Example {
    CANCELLED,
    RUNNING,
    WAITING,
    FINISHED
}

enum Example {
    GREEN(0, 255, 0),
    RED(255, 0, 0)
}
```

Comment: Still looks wrong in the eclipse previewer for me but when I tried it on the actual source it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, could you post the corresponding XML markup from a eclipse-codeformatter.xml?

Answer (score 51):

You can specify this in your formatter preferences:

- Preferences: Java -- Code Style -- Formatter
- Click Edit
- Select the 'Line Wrapping' tab
- Select 'enum' declaration -> Constants in the box on the left
- Set Line wrapping policy to 'Wrap all elements, every element on a new line'
- Check 'Force split...'

Comment: I had this problem for months.  The thing I didn't try was "force split".  Not sure why it should be needed as you'd think "wrap all elements" would actually wrap all elements!  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 11):

It's slightly ugly too, but if your company policy prevents you from changing the formatter, you can just put comments at the end of lines you don't want to be wrapped.

```
public static enum Command 
{
    login,//
    register,//
    logout,//
    newMessage//
};
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not nice but you can turn the Eclipse formatter off for some sections of code...

```
// @formatter:off
public static enum Command {
    login,
    register,
    logout,
    newMessage
};
// @formatter:on
```

the option is in the Windows->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter->Edit->Off/On Tags panel

Comment: This works...kind of.  The compiler now thinks its an error.  Putting them in comments overcomes this problem like // @formatter:off

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the line wrapping policy under enum declaration for "Constants."

Set the wrapping policy to

- Wrap all elements, every element on a new line

**AND**

- Check the box that says "Force Split, even if line shorter than,,,,,

Answer (score 2):

Just adding latest Eclipse 2018.9

1. `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter` - `Edit`
2. Expand `Line Wrapping` tree node.
3. Expand `Wrapping settings`
4. Expand `'enum' declaration`
5. Edit `Constants` and `Constant arguments`.

Constants need to be `Wrap all elements, every element on a new line`.
Constant arguments need to be `Wrap where necessary`.

Answer (score 1):

in my case set `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_enum_constants` to `17` works with maven formatter plugin: https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/

```
    <setting
      id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_enum_constants"
      value="17"
    />
```

https://gitlab.inria.fr/stopcovid19/submission-code-server/-/blob/develop/.etc/eclipse-formatter-java.xml

Comment: awesome, any clue where the doc stands for those values?