# Force line-breaks in eclipse CDT formatter

Tags: formatting, eclipse-cdt, line-breaks

I'm trying to get Eclipse to stop squashing my enums onto a single line. When searching online I keep seeing people (eg [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676305/how-to-stop-eclipse-formatter-from-placing-all-enums-on-one-line?rq=1)) referring to a 'force split' checkbox, but I'm not seeing one in my Formatter options (in CDT Juno). Is this a java-specific option?

There is a checkbox 'never join already-wrapped lines', is this what they mean? Unfortunately I already Formatted my files assuming that 'every element on a new line' actually meant 'every element on a new line', so this doesn't help

On the 'Line Wrapping' tab I have selected 'Wrap all elements, every element on a new line', but this doesn't seem to be having any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's Java specific.  I downloaded the CDT version of Juno and the 'force split' checkbox is there.

[image: CDT Formatter]

My version of [CDT Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR1/eclipse-cpp-juno-SR1-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz) was: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800

Comment: Hm, I downloaded the most recent version and the checkbox is indeed there now, I must have been using a pre-release candidate or something. Thanks!